# Add Dynamic Title to Axes in D3

Tags: d3.js, title, axes

I'm using the following code:

```
// Add title to y axis
svg.append("text")
   .attr("x", -500)
   .attr("y", -100)
   .attr("text-anchor", "left")
   .attr("transform", "rotate(270)")
   .style("font-size", "16px")
   .text("Test");
```

How can I have the text to be derived from the result of a function instead of being a string literal? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass in a function `.text`, e.g. to set the text value to be the time at execution:

```
.text(function(){ return new Date(); })
```

If you want the text value to depend on data, then you need to [bind data](https://www.dashingd3js.com/binding-data-to-dom-elements) to the text element first.